# Разделитель SplitPane из JavaFX не реагирует на попытки изменения положение

Tags: java, javafx, scene-builder

Настройка положения разделителя (`Divider Positions`) - пожалуй первая настройка, которую чаще всего нужно изменить при работе со `SplitPane`. На данный момент `SceneBuilder` за меня решил, что она должна иметь значение `0.758`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никакие попытки изменить эту координату мышью изменений не дают:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытки ввести новое значение `Divider Positions` тоже ничего не дают. Как видно, несмотря на то, что значение равно `0.5`, разделитель не посередине, а там же, где и был:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли Вас, дорогие эксперты, какие-нибудь объяснения происходящего?

Comment: Возможно у вас ширина левой панели жестко задана (или ширина обеих панелей).

Comment: Вы код лейаута покажите, а не скриншоты...

Comment: Уточните откуда вы не можете его поменять, из скомпилированного состояния или SceneBuilder. Возможно у правой анкорпейн стоит MAX SIZE который вы скорее всего, изменить и не можете.

Comment: @insolor, Perfect Voyage, Вы правы! Благодарю Вас за подсказку!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как заметили @insolor и @PerfectVoyage, первой причиной было наличие жестких размеров (в данном случае у левой панели было установлено 320px). Однако когда я убрал эту жесткую величину, то divider ещё не двигался. Задвигался лишь после того, как я установил параметру `Min Width` значение `USE_COMUTED_SIZE` вместо `USE_PREF_SIZE`.